# How to fix: linq query returns @p_linq_0 instead of variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My linq query returns @p_linq_0.

```
public IEnumerable<CheckListItem> GetByCheckListGroup(int id)
{
  int integer = id;
  var connection = context.CheckListItems
    .Where(p => p.fkCheckListGroupID == integer)
    .AsEnumerable();
  return connection;
}
```

An id of 7 comes through but the query replaces it with @p_linq_0

```
WHERE [Extent1].[fkCheckListGroupID] = @p__linq__0
```

without the where clause the query is perfect.

even if i change it to 
`.Where(p => p.fkCheckListGroupID.Equals(integer))` the same outcome.
If i hard code it, it works.

i expect `WHERE [Extent1].[fkCheckListGroupID] = 7` instead of @p_linq_0

query returns

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[pkSOCheckListItemID] AS [pkSOCheckListItemID], 
    [Extent1].[fkCheckListGroupID] AS [fkCheckListGroupID], 
    [Extent1].[pfCode] AS [pfCode], 
    [Extent1].[pfDescription] AS [pfDescription], 
    [Extent1].[pfState] AS [pfState], 
    [Extent1].[pfDefinition] AS [pfDefinition], 
    [Extent1].[pfExplanation] AS [pfExplanation], 
    [Extent1].[afName] AS [afName], 
    [Extent1].[afOrder] AS [afOrder], 
    [Extent1].[sfCreatedDate] AS [sfCreatedDate], 
    [Extent1].[sfLastModifiedDate] AS [sfLastModifiedDate], 
    [Extent1].[sfCreatedBy] AS [sfCreatedBy], 
    [Extent1].[sfLastModifiedBy] AS [sfLastModifiedBy]
    FROM [dbo].[CheckListItem] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[fkCheckListGroupID] = @p__linq__0
```

SSMS message: Must declare the scalar variable "@p_linq_0"

Comment: `@p__linq__0` is a query parameter, what problem/issue is it causing you?

Comment: it's not producing the sql query that is expected.

Comment: You mean the result set that's returned is incorrect? Have you set a break point on your `integer` variable to see what that is?

Comment: the result set returns null

Comment: interger variable: yes i have, and it's 7

Comment: "i expect WHERE [Extent1].[fkCheckListGroupID] = 7 instead of @p_linq_0" - that's an incorrect expectation; I would *absolutely* expect this to be parameterized, and it is; so let's take a step back - what is the actual *problem* - it isn't the query, so: what are you seeing? you say "the result set returns null" - by that, do you mean it is returning zero rows? How are you using it? Can you show the code that actually consumes this? because right now you're returning an open query, etc

Comment: That is completely normal for Entity Framework. It will parameterize all your... well parameters... Which is what you should do when writing SQL anyway. What you are posting is not the complete SQL generated by EF, which is usally surrounded by `exec sp_executesql N'......'` followed by the parameters, which in you case would be `@p__linq__0 int, @p__linq__0=7`.

Comment: @MarCGravell Yes returning zero rows. IEnumerable<CheckListItem> m_cli = _repository.GetByCheckListGroup(id)

Comment: @JodyPretorius then: there are zero matching rows! this will be either a: because of the data, or b: because of something else you're doing to the `IEnumerable<T>` *after* this. Note: returning `IEnumerable<T>` is probably a bad idea here, IMO

Comment: Try using the SQL profiler to have a look at the actual generated SQL. Because as I said, what you pasted here, is not the complete query.

Comment: @MarcGravell When i hard code the Where(p => p.fkCheckListGroupID == integer) to Where(p => p.fkCheckListGroupID == 7) it changes the WHERE [Extent1].[fkCheckListGroupID] = '@p__linq__0' to WHERE 7 = [Extent1].[fkCheckListGroupID] and returns a row of data as it should.

Comment: @MikalSchachtJensen i'll do that and get back to you

Comment: What type is fkCheckListGroupID, both in your database and in your entity type?

Comment: @JodyPretorius coding to a literal constant might result in a different query - that's fine and is up to the query generator - but if you're getting different *results* then: **I think that `integer` is not what you think it is**, i.e. it isn't 7.

Comment: I don't have access to SQL Profiler and our DBA is busy, but i have solved the issue. i noticed other scripts of the same kind weren't giving any issues. The other scripts however where using strings instead of int. I converted both ID's to strings, checked if they are equal and it works. i don't like this, and would like it to work properly. for the time being i'll leave it like this and hand it over to our senior to evaluate.

Comment: what type is fkCheckListGroupID, in database and in model? Note the parameterised query is not the problem, most likely the comparison is incorrect because of incompatible types.

Comment: its an int. They're both int. currently I've done a .ToSting() on both. and it works.

Answer (score 0):

That's just standard Entity Framework behaviour.  Queries are parameterised, so what you'll see in the object `connection` is the parameterised query.  The values for parameters will also be in the object.  When the query executes the parameter values are used, but the query string you'll see, if for instance you use SQL Server Profiler, will show the parameter names in places like where clauses and have the parameter values at the end of the query string.

What is executed is a built in stored procedure, sp_executesql.  That stored procedure is passed the query string, which contains the parameters, and arguments for each parameter.  The parameter arguments are further query strings for defining the parameters and giving them values.

If you're seeing no results in when the query is executed, e.g. by calling `ToList` on the `connection` object, then there aren't any matching rows in the table being queried.

There are a couple of ways to check the query that is executed.  One is to run SQL Server Profiler and then run the code.  Find the execution of the query in the profiler results.  You'll be able to copy the query that was executed and run that.  However, since you have the query, albeit without parameters, you could take what you have and define the parameters yourself.  Or even construct the call to `sp_executesql` yourself.  It should look something like this:

```sql
exec sp_executesql(N'<your parameterised query string here>', N'@p_linq_0 int', N'@p_linq_0 = 7')
```